# Spring MVC selected value in form:selected after form validation error

Tags: forms, validation, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with the validation form, the form have a lot of different fields (input text fields, select option, multiple select option...). I have developed all the logical sourcecode about validation form with spring security, but when the validation form fails (for example, a user don't fill anything) and reload the form again all the input text fields are correctly filled but the select option and multiple select options have been deleted and the user must select it again. Why not get filled as the text fields?

This is a piece of my view:

```
    <tr>
            <td><form:label path="TechContactName"><spring:message code="label.techcontactname"/><sup>*</sup></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="TechContactName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="techContactName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr> 


<tr>
            <td><form:label path="LicenseProduct"><spring:message code="label.licenseproduct"/><sup>*</sup></form:label></td>
            <td><form:select path="licenseProduct" id="selectProduct" size="6" >
                        <option >Option 1</option>
                        <option >Option 2</option>
                        <option >Option 3</option>
                        <option >Option 4</option>
                        <option >Option 5</option>
                        <option >Option 6</option>
                </form:select></td>
            <td><form:errors path="licenseProduct" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td><form:label path="DeployCountries"><spring:message code="label.deploycountries"/><sup>*</sup></form:label></td>
            <td><form:select path="deployCountries" id="selectCountries" multiple="multiple" >
                       <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                       <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                       <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                       <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                       <option value="FR">France</option>
                       <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                </form:select> </td>
           <td><form:errors path="deployCountries" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
```

And my controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addLicense(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value="license")  LicenseEntity license, BindingResult result, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("validation errors size..."+result.getErrorCount());

            return "editLicenseList";
        } else {
            //all works correctly           
        }

    }
```

The form input text field si correctly filled when the validation fails but the form:select and form:select multiple fail and reload the form with any value selected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Spring's `<form:option>` tag, rather than the HTML's own `<option>` tag. This will ensure that the option remains selected after validation failure (because Spring will set the `selected` attribute).

```
<form:select path="licenseProduct" id="selectProduct" size="6" >
    <form:option value="Option 1"/>
    <form:option value="Option 2"/>
    <form:option value="Option 3"/>
    <form:option value="Option 4"/>
    <form:option value="Option 5"/>
    <form:option value="Option 6"/>
</form:select>
```

And

```
<form:select path="deployCountries" id="selectCountries" multiple="multiple" >
    <form:option value="AT" label="Austria"/>
    <form:option value="BE" label="Belgium"/>
    <form:option value="DK" label="Denmark"/>
    <form:option value="FI" label="Finland"/>
    <form:option value="FR" label="France"/>
    <form:option value="DE" label="Germany"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thanks Will Keeling very much!! The simple select works perfectly, but the multiple select not, if I select more than one option after validate the form and reload it again didn't select anything, Is there any way to keep the selected?

Comment: Can you use the debugger to check that the list of `LicenseEntity.deployCountries` in the model is populated after submitting the form? The values of this list needs to match what the `value` in the `<form:option>` tag expects - so one or more of the strings `AT`, `BE`, etc