# preserve multiple select values on from submission errors

Tags: forms, jsp, select, html-select

I have a form in which there is a multiple select field along with a lot of other fields. On form submission, if there is any error I'm rendering the same form with the pre filled values that are entered by the user.

The problem is that in case of multiple select, I'm only able to preserve the first value of the selected items.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <form:label class="control-label col-sm-3 required" path="tags">Tag</form:label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <form:select multiple="multiple" name="tags" class="form-control select-search" required="required" type="select" data-placeholder="Select a Tag" path="tags">
            <c:forEach items="${MyConstants.TAGS}" var="tag_element">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${not empty param.tags}">
                        <c:forEach items="${param.tags}" var="param_tag">
                            <option value="${tag_element}" ${param_tag == tag_element ? 'selected' : ''}>${tag_element}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                     </c:when>
                     <c:otherwise>
                         <option value="${tag_element}">"${tag_element}"</option>
                     </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose> 
             </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using html's  tag, use  tag which will automatically preserve the values without setting any select. Thanks to this post: [Spring MVC selected value in form:selected after form validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451656/spring-mvc-selected-value-in-formselected-after-form-validation-error?rq=1)