# Selected Tag dissapears after form validation and submition in JSP

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm a beginner in Spring and I'm trying to fix some small problem in my application. I have a form to edit the user profile. In this form, I have one dropdown list where admin user can select user role for the user that is being edited. When I'm going to edit user page then all data in form are populated from the database. Let's say I have two inputs in the form: `input` with **lastName** and `select` with **user role**. The select element contains all the roles that exist in the database but the selected role is matched to the role that the user actually have assigned.

This is part of my form - input lastName

```
<spring:bind path="lastName">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
        <form:input path="lastName" type="text" class="form-control ${status.error ? 'border border-danger' : ''}" id="lastName" />
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
    </div>
</spring:bind>
```

and this is a select element:

```
<form:select path="roles" id="role" multiple="false">
    <form:options items="${allRoles}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="role"/>
</form:select>
```

Now, when I want to edit lastName eg. leave the blank field, then spring validates this field and throws an error. The problem is that role that was previously selected in `select` element is now unselected.

This is page HTML before validation:

input:

```
<div class="form-group  ">
        <label for="email" class="active">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" value="ola@test.com">
</div>
```

select:

```
<select id="role" name="roles"">
<option value="1">ADMIN</option>
<option value="2">USER</option>
<option value="3">STUDENT</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">LECTURER</option>
</select>
```

and once lastName field is cleared and form submited:
input:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="">Last name</label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" class="form-control border border-danger" value="">
        <span id="lastName.errors" style="color: #ff0000;">This field is required.</span>
</div>
```

select:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="role">Role Id</label>
<select id="role" name="roles">
<option value="1">ADMIN</option>
<option value="2">USER</option>
<option value="3">STUDENT</option>
<option value="4">LECTURER</option>
</select>
</div>
```

As you can see `selected= "selected"` attribute has disappeared from option 4. How to prevent this? Btw. I'm aware of this [Spring MVC selected value in form:selected after form validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451656/spring-mvc-selected-value-in-formselected-after-form-validation-error)

but it seems that this isn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some tip in archived page [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EaERJS6hnRIJ:forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/84199-form-select-options-not-selecting-right-after-validate-if-errors%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl)

Now selected attribute is not removed from the option tag. I'm not sure if this is good way to solve this, but it works for me..

Modified select:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="editForm">
        <c:forEach items="${editForm.roles}" var="role">
            <c:set var="userRoleId" value="${role.id}" scope="request"/>
        </c:forEach>

        <form:select path="roles" id="role" multiple="false">
            <c:forEach var="tempRole" items="${allRoles}">
                <option value="${tempRole.id}" <c:if test="${tempRole.id == userRoleId}">selected="selected"</c:if> value="${tempRole.id}">${tempRole.role}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
</form:form>
```